# Can automated GUI test cases written for project without entry point (without main class)?

Tags: gui-testing, fest, jemmy

I am working on a project where there is no necessity of having an entry point (without a main class). I have been thinking about implementing few GUI test cases using FEST or Jemmy (using NetBeans IDE). Is it possible to automate GUI tests without an entry point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a testing-framework like FEST does not need a main Class. The test is executed by a Testrunner provided by JUnit or TestNG. The fixtures to access the GUI Components are created by the public constructors of your Elements. So like for every Unit test there is no need for a main method.

Here is a [tutorial for FEST](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077740/open-source-tools/test-driven-gui-development-with-fest.html).